# Angularjs parameter to html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form that allows to update all the fields of an element. After the update succeeded, I want to redirect to the page with the list of all elements. I want to pass this page the message "update succeeded".

In the controller I pass a parameter to the state provider in this way:

```
$state.go('list', { message: "Update success" }, { reload: true });
```

In the state provider:

```
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('list',
                {
                    url: '/List',
                    templateUrl: 'elementsList.html',
                    params: {
                        message:
                            function ($stateParams) {
                                return $stateParams.message;
                            }
                    }
                })
```

Is this the correct way to pass a string parameter to an html page?
What is the syntax in the html page to show the parameter value?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

```
function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('list',
     {
       url: '/List/:message',
       templateUrl: 'elementsList.html'
     }
})
```

an then access it in the controller like this. `$stateParams.message`
Don't forget to inject $stateParams in your controller. You can easily assign the value to a $scope variable `$scope.message = $stateParams.message` and use {{message}} in your view to display it.

Note that there's also an event:

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', 
function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ ... })
```

The parameter can be accessed with `toParams.message` in this case.

Comment: Thank you, this way I can see the message in the controller and assign it to $scope, but {{ message }} is not filled and I don't see it in the page.

Comment: What happens if you define $scope.myData = {message: $stateParams.message} and use {{myData.message}}? Be aware that you should avoid using primitives like explained [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)